# Conditional compilation of React native apps

Tags: android, ios, react-native, npm

We have single code base from which we create two different apps.
But there are some packages/SDKs which are not required in one of the these apps.

So we want to exclude them at the compile time only so it doesn't increase the app size. And at runtime we can check if the package/SDK is available using inline requires or something similar.

Has anyone implemented something on the similar lines or could provide a direction for such implementation?

It will be very helpful.